# How to disable Crashlytics for iOS during development?

Tags: ios, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

Is there any way to disable crash reporting for Ad-Hoc builds? I only want crash reporting for release builds.

I know I can use following code but it only work debug builds.

```
#if DEBUG == 0
    [Fabric with:@[CrashlyticsKit]];
#endif
```

Im using Fabric 1.1.3

Edit: I don't want to disable Fabric at all, I just need automatic configurations for Ad-Hoc and Release builds.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable Crashlytics iOS library using a flag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28931322/how-to-disable-crashlytics-ios-library-using-a-flag)

Comment: No, I needed automatic configurations for Ad-Hoc and Release builds, and @rckoenes solution works in that case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66972059/2692839

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Development builds are also `DEBUG` builds, You are probably meaning Ad-Hoc builds.
Since the release and Ad-Hoc build use the same configuration you will not be able to tell them apart.

You bets option is to create a new configuration for the AppStore. For this configuration add a `Preprocessor Macro`, Like `FABRIC=1`

Then in you build code:

```
#ifdef FABRIC
    [Fabric with:@[CrashlyticsKit]];
#endif
```

Answer (score 9):

To disable firebase crashlytics for debug mode in swift:

```
    #if DEBUG
        Crashlytics.crashlytics().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(false)
    #endif
```

Comment: Read the documentation for this method just in case, you may want to use info plist instead.

Answer (score 5):

I think you can try this :

```
#ifndef DEBUG
 [Fabric with:@[CrashlyticsKit]];
#endif
```

Comment: In preprocessing syntax, `ifndef DEBUG` and `if DEBUG == 0` are not the same at all, because the second one imply that DEBUG is defined with a 0 value and often in release builds, the DEBUG flaf is just not present

Answer (score 5):

If you use Swift, this woud work:

```
#if !DEBUG
    Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

For Swift, Add this key to plist and set it 'NO'.

```
firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled
```

After this, based on user-defined variable in Build Settings, you can configure this.

```
#if Development
print("Debug 1")
Fabric.sharedSDK().debug = true
#else
print("Debug 0")
Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
#endif
```